# how to create an isoletated component for a razor page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor, blazor

At my job they ask me to create a "component" for directions, it will have 3 to 4 combobox to choose a direction,that component will be use in another pages, we are working with razor pages, i dont know how to do it or where to find info, anyone can help me?

Comment: Hello, please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that other experts have enough information to assist you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might improve your question by producing an [mre]. Please note that this is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Components are just separate razor files.
So to make a component for directions, create a Directions.razor file and add your combo boxes here. then to use that component somewhere else you just add it as a tag like  along with any parameters you add to it. I would suggest reading up on Blazor components as it will help you along the way.

The [Microsoft Docs for Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#:%7E:text=Blazor%20apps%20are%20based%20on,NET%20C%23%20classes%20built%20into%20.) talks about components and will be a good start!